# Explanation of __do_IRQ function

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, interrupt-handling

I'm preparing a presentation on how the Linux kernel handles interrupts based on the book Understanding the Linux Kernel ny Bovet & Cesati. The cover says it covers Version 2.6. However, I can't quite figure out how the given __do_IRQ() function is supposed to work. Although I've done some (basic) C programming, I can't understand some of the instructions.

```
    spin_lock(&(irq_desc[irq].lock));
    irq_desc[irq].handler->ack(irq);
    irq_desc[irq].status &= ~(IRQ_REPLAY | IRQ_WAITING);
    irq_desc[irq].status |= IRQ_PENDING;
    if (!(irq_desc[irq].status & (IRQ_DISABLED | IRQ_INPROGRESS)) && irq_desc[irq].action){
irq_desc[irq].status |= IRQ_INPROGRESS;
    do{
     irq_desc[irq].status &= ~IRQ_PENDING;
     spin_unlock(&(irq_desc[irq].lock));
     handle_IRQ_event(irq,regs,irq_desc[irq].action);
     spin_lock(&(irq_desc[irq].lock));
   }while (irq_desc[irq].status & IRQ_PENDING);
   irq_desc[irq].status &= ~IRQ_INPROGRESS;
}
   irq_desc[irq].handler->end(irq);
   spin_unlock(&(irq_desc[irq].lock));
```

My questions are the following:

1. How does the assignment of .status work? The book says its a set of flags. I get that the flags are the uppercase variables, but how are they accessed in this scenario? Shouldn't it be .status.IRQ_SOMETHING or something like that?
2. What does the single "&" mean in the condition of the if expression?

Comment: Isn't this question just asking "what are operators in C"?

Comment: Read this [tutorial on bit manipulation in C](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html) or do a google search on the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer in reverse order.

The `&` is the "bitwise AND" operator; just like `|` is the "bitwise OR" operator. Given an integer variable `x`, the expression:

```
  x |= (1U << n);
```

Sets bit `n` of `x` to `1`.  Conversely:

```
  x &= ~(1U << n);
```

Clears bit `n` of `x`, setting it to `0`.

Given an understanding of this operator, you can see how the `.status` field works - it is an integer field, and various flags are turned on and off by using the operators mentioned above.  The flags are checked using the `&` operator:

```
  irq_desc[irq].status & (IRQ_DISABLED | IRQ_INPROGRESS)
```

Yields a true result when either of the `IRQ_DISABLED` or `IRQ_INPROGRESS` bits is set in the `.status` field.